# Vb6 form inside a panel in .net framework

Tags: .net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a vb.net program that I need to call a vb6 form and place into a panel. I'm trying to find the code to do this through the interop layer and I'm having issues finding examples. Any ideas how to make the panel load the vb6 control. [The form I'm trying to call is the frmAccount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGmbQ.png)

Comment: I don't know anythnig about .Net, but would [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19368/Embedding-of-VB6-form-in-NET-applications) help at all?

Comment: Do you want to place a form or a UserControl in a panel?

Comment: Is that VB6 form an [unsuspecting one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)?

Comment: Can you please add some more details? Also in one place you say its a VB6 form, and another a control. What .NET GUI framework are you using? WinForms or WPF or... ?

Comment: winforms is what we are usings

Comment: You could probably expose this Form as a public COM class through a Class Module on the VB6 side and then consume it from your VB.Net program. .Net has no trouble consuming COM classes.